# Problem with from twilio.rest import client error?

Tags: twilio, importerror

I'm trying to use the Twilio sandbox to message to my Whatsapp number but I'm repeatedly getting this
ImportError...
My code is as followed...

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client()

from_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:Twilio number'
to_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:Own number'

client.messages.create(body= 'Ahoy World!',
                      from_= from_whatsapp_number,
                      to=to_whatsapp_number)
```

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Comment: What is the exact text of the error? Could you add it to your question? Also, could you clarify if you get this error all the time or just sometimes? It also helps if you tag your question with the language you're using, it gets more exposure.